# Errors with multicolumn-equations inside tabular (inside tcolorbox)

Tags: math-mode, errors, boxes

I try to rebuild a fairly complicated math-table, and I'm almost satisfied with the result. The MWE actually compiles to the table I want, but with error messages. When I include the table in my real (big) document, I get the error messages too, but in that case the document doesn't compile anymore.

I spent quite some time experimenting with and checking the `$`, but cannot find the error, and would be grateful for any tip.

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[listings,theorems]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{before={\par\medskip\pagebreak[0]\noindent},after={\par\medskip}}%

\begin{document}


\newcounter{texercise}[chapter]
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!5,colframe=blue!50!black,arc=0mm,
theorem={Algebra}{texercise}{(Vereinfachter) Datentyp 'Liste'}{myMarker}]{}
\medskip


\begin{tabular}{llll}
 \textbf{algebra}  &  $list_1$  &  &  \\
 \textbf{sorts}    & \multicolumn{3}{l}{$list$, $elem$ \{$bool$ ist im folgenden immer implizit dabei\}}  \\
 \textbf{ops}      &  $empty$   &  $:$      &  $\to list$   \\
                   &  $first$   &  $:list$  &  $\to elem$   \\
                   &  $append$    &  $:list$  &  $\to list$   \\
                   &  $concat$    &  $:list \times elem$  &  $\to list$   \\
                   &  $isempty$    &  $:list \times list$  &  $\to bool$   \\
\textbf{sets}      &  $list$  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$= \{ <a_1,\dots,a_n> \mid n \ge 0, a_i \in elem$\}}\\
\textbf{functions} & & & \\
                  &   $empty$ & \multicolumn{2}{l}{ $ = \Diamond$}\\
                  &   \multicolumn{3}{l}{
                     \begin{equation*}
                     $first(a_1 \dots a_n) =$
                       \begin{cases}
                         $a_1$ & \text{falls $n>0$} \\
                         undefiniert & \text{sonst}
                       \end{cases}
                     \end{equation*}}  \\
\textbf{end} $list_1$ & & & \\

\end{tabular}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Here is the error message:

```
ERROR: Missing $ inserted.

--- TeX said ---
<inserted text> 
            $
l.36                      \end{equation*}}
                                        \\
--- HELP ---
TeX probably found a command that can be used only in math mode when
it wasn't in math mode....
```

And here is the result:

[image: MWE result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for `equation*` in order to use the `cases` environment. Just use the following definition:

```
%... 
& \multicolumn{3}{l}{%
  $first(a_1 \dots a_n) =
    \begin{cases}
      a_1 & \text{falls $n>0$} \\
      \text{undefiniert} & \text{sonst}
    \end{cases}$} \\
%...
```

[image]

In part, the problem was that you're using `equation*` and then initiating math mode using `$`...`$`. An `equation*` already initiates math mode, so the use of `$` is not needed.

You may also wish to use `\langle`...`\rangle` instead of `<`...`>` for your list notation.

Comment: It took me a while to check that out, but if I follow your example exactly, both the MWE and the real document compile - thanks a lot. What caused a lot of confusion on my side was the fact, that the way you positioned the '$` resulted in a (completely) wrong fontification in my Emacs buffer, but it works. Putting more '$' in the formula restores the correct fontification, but results in LaTeX errors.

Comment: @user17106: Yes, some editors rely on the use of explicit math environments or switches (like `$`) in order to display the correct syntax highlighting. Mixing these in odd locations (like an `equation*` environment inside a `tabular`, say) causes the engine to not pick up on it properly, I guess. Perhaps advisable to submit a bug report to the editor programmers. It may be that the syntax parser has a number of exclusions in it for ad-hoc - yet completely appropriate in LaTeX terms - configurations. I don't know much about it, but have seen that in other editors.

Comment: Including the \begin{cases} and \end{cases} inside $...$ doesn't seem right at first sight, and thus Emacs puts the whole part in math-font. But if I exclude the begin and end expressions by setting more $, there are LaTeX errors, strangely enough. But anyway, it works fine now, thanks.